# What is the best way to store a long list of random numbers?

Tags: algorithm, list, numbers

I am looking for an algorithm which stores a long list (possibly thousands) of random numbers and retrieves them efficiently. Typically the solution should not require any sorting of data i.e the numbers are stored as they are generated, And the storage space required should be less than that required for an array/hash of such numbers. New numbers can be added to the list.

Comment: `space required should be less than that required for an array...` I doubt that.

Comment: Is there a certain range in which these numbers exist? and are these numbers unique ?

Comment: Well, since we're talking about pseudo-random numbers, just save the pattern. That will use the least amount of space (scnr).

Comment: How 'efficiently' does it need to retrieve them?

Comment: disclaimer: humoristic comment. http://xkcd.com/221/ (and you only need 3 bits to store it)

Comment: Do you have control over how the numbers are generated?

Comment: It's worth pointing out that a list of (genuinely) random numbers is not compressible.  A good working definition of 'random' is that any series of such numbers cannot be represented by anything shorter than the series itself; after all, if the numbers could be predicted by any means they wouldn't be random.  As for pseudo-random numbers, there's already plenty of good advice hereabouts.

Comment: What does "retrieve" mean? Look up by value, look up by index in the list, something else?

Comment: Agree with high performance. If you can express `n` random numbers using `m` other numbers  with `m < n` then they are not really random.

Comment: Ì Dont want to store the numbers as it is, becos that would require some space. I am looking for something which only stores the initial number or the last number and stores the other numbers in terms of some relationship between those numbers.

Comment: The numbers are totally random; can not be represented by a pattern.

Comment: @RJadhav: if the numbers really are random over the full range of values of their type, then like Mark says there does not exist a relationship between them that takes less space to store than the numbers themselves. Obviously if the numbers are random in the range, for example, 1-63 then you could pack them into 6 bits per value.

Comment: @SteveJessop Look up by value.

Comment: Do you not realize that 'some relationship between those numbers' and 'can not be represented by a pattern' are directly contradictory?

Comment: @JimBalter think what i meant by that was, i want to store them as anything other than numbers so that they would require less space.

Comment: Regardless of what you meant, truly random sequences are not compressible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Stemm has a very good idea of just storing the seed to the pseudo-random number generator (prng).  The count of the numbers would also be required so that you would know how many times to call prng to retrieve them.

If you don't have access to the seed or the numbers are otherwise random, then you might have another option.  If your numbers are integers, not very big, and you know there are no duplicates, then consider storing them as bits.  So, for example, if your longest value fits in a 2 byte int, then that value could be stored by using 1 bit.  Some examples:

0 = 1.

4 = 10000 binary or 10 hex.

10 = 10000000000 binary.

If the largest value is 65535, which is the largest value that can fit inside of a 16 bit unsigned integer, then the amount of memory to hold all the values can be calculated as 65536 / 8 = 8192 bytes.  If you are using Java, take a look at the `java.util.BitSet` or `java.math.BigInteger` classes to help do this.

Answer (score 2):

Try to implement any of [pseudo-random generators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator). All you need - just to store initial seed (which must be random). But, of course - accessing to any element of pseudo-random sequence will have complexity O(N). It's just [space-time tradeoff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space%E2%80%93time_tradeoff).

Answer (score 0):

If the numbers are truly random or even if they come from a sufficiently good RNG for which you don't know the seed, it is impossible to compress them. For a particular compression scheme you might get lucky and draw a compressible set of numbers, but the probability of such event is always very small.

This comes from the counting argument (aka the pigeonhole argument), there just arent enough bitstrings of length less than `n` to encode every string of length `n`. The popular compression schemes go around this by taking advantage of the fact that only a small subset of the input strings is probable. This small set (e.g. English text, executable binaries, etc.) is then fully encodible on shorter strings.

With fully random strings there is no such backdoor, therefore meaningful compression is impossible.